Creating a query in Microsoft ADO that searches Test Cases by Execution Date
I need to be able to generate a daily report that shows how many test cases are executed daily at each board level. Queries seem to be the way to go, but I can't seem to figure out how to search for all of the test cases that have been executed on today's date, or on a certain range of dates.
I've tried "Work Item Type = Test Case" and "Finish Date @StartOfDay" but "finish date" doesn't seem to be a field for date of test execution.
What's the best way to query test cases based on either a specific date of execution, or a range of dates for execution?

I understand your requirement to list the test cases that are executed every day; however, we cannot use work item query to get such information, because the execution information is managed with Test Points in Test Plans rather than work items in Azure Boards.

Since your requirement is to generate a report to monitor the daily test execution, I would suggest using Power BI to collect the results. Here are my brief steps for your reference and please see more details in the documents below.
Power BI integration and supported connections methods - Azure DevOps | Microsoft Learn
Use OData queries to generate Power BI reports - Azure DevOps | Microsoft Learn
Connect to Power BI Data Connector - Azure DevOps | Microsoft Learn

Create a custom Analytics view to list all test cases;

Connect to the custom Analytics view in Power BI and get the TestCases - Today table;

Add the resource imported from the sample query below to get DailyTestPointsHistory table;
let
   Source = OData.Feed ("https://analytics.dev.azure.com/<YourAzureDevOpsOrgName>/<TheProjectName>/_odata/v3.0-preview/TestPointHistorySnapshot?"
        &"$filter= "
            &"DateSK eq 20240411 "
            &"and AnalyticsUpdatedDate ge 2024-04-11T00:00:00.0000000Z "
            &"and AnalyticsUpdatedDate le 2024-04-11T23:59:59.0000000Z "
        &"&$select=TestCaseId,ResultOutcome,AnalyticsUpdatedDate "
    ,null, [Implementation="2.0",OmitValues = 
ODataOmitValues.Nulls,ODataVersion = 4])
in
    Source



Create a new table DailyReport referencing the DailyTestPointsHistory table and add new empty columns;

Add mapping value in the new DailyReport table to populate more test case work item information;

We can refresh the source tables after the query is modified or new test cases are executed; and the report will be updated accordingly. (There is a delay when new results are generated and retrieved in the analytics data.)


